# How to save jzy3d chart to file

Tags: java, charts, jzy3d

```
ChartLauncher.openChart(chart)
```

Doesn't work for me*, so I'd like something like `ChartSaver.saveChart(chart, path)` if such a thing exists.

*I get:

```
libEGL warning: failed to create a pipe screen for i965
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `chart` object must have a method called `screenshot` which accepts a `File` to export the chart as image.

```
File image = new File("image.png");
chart.screenshot(image);
```